# Java Access Modifier and NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, access-modifiers

I am getting a runtime error in my Java code, and I'm trying to understand the reason behind it.  The two static access modifiers between double asterisks are the items in question.  The code compiles with or without these modifiers (asterisks removed of course).  But at runtime, it only runs without an error when the modifiers are present.  Why is this?  The error generated at runtime when the static modifiers are not present is pasted below the code.  Thank you so much for your help!

Here is the code:

```
public class Blue {


    public int[][] multiArray(int x, int y){

        int[][] myArray = new int[x][y];
        return myArray;

    }

    static Blue blueObject = new Blue();

    public **static** int[][] one = blueObject.multiArray(3,3); 
    public **static** int[][] two = blueObject.multiArray(3,3);

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("Hello world!");

    }

}
```

Error generated at runtime **without** the static access modifiers:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Blue.<init>(Blue.java:13)
    at Blue.<clinit>(Blue.java:11)
```

Comment: works for me. check it out here http://ideone.com/eyOn0x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to how JVM deals with class loading and how your class is defined.
When you have  **static** int[][] one, it works because JVM read/load static code by the same order as they represented in the class. So when JVM tries to initialize int[][] one, the **static** Blue blueObject is ready for use.

However if you declare int[][] one as **non-static**, when JVM try to create **static** Blue 
blueObject, it has to create a fully initialized Blue object and assign it to **static** blueobject, so it tries to initialize the int[][]; but at this moment, your static **blueObject**.multiArray(3,3); is not ready yet.

I hopethis make sense to your question.

Comment: This makes perfect sense.  I just want to verify, it's **not** that instance variables are compiled before static variables.  Rather, the issue here is that when I call the constructor Blue(), it is trying to initialize the object's instance variables that are assigned to values provided by the object itself.  Since the blueObject does not exist yet, this is not possible, which generated the error.  I just wanted to repeat what you said in my own words to make sure I understand it properly.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes that's right. I will put a sample code in a answer box to make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you declared blueObject as static, chang the definition to:

```
Test blueObject = new Test();
```

and it will run!

Either work in "singleton mode" (everything is static) or in "object mode" (where you create an object and call the class methods through the object) - you can't have both.

Answer (score 0):

@user1419674
**Normally** JVM will initialize static variables first and then instance variables. And also the static variables are initialized only once at the first time the code is invoked.

```
public class Test {
    public Test(){
        System.out.println("constructor of class Test");
    }
}

public class App {
    private Test test = new Test();
    private static int s_i;
    static {
        s_i = 1;
        System.out.println("initializing static field");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        App app1 = new App();
        App app2 = new App();
    }
}
```

Running code above will print out :

```
initializing static field
constructor of class Test
constructor of class Test
```

However, in your code, the static variable is of type of Blue itself. And the it becomes like the initialization of **static Blue blueObject** depends on the initialization of **int[][] one** which in true requires **static Blue blueObject**.